# Discord.js Ban command issues

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to fix an error that I have gotten today, the error is this:

> C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord
>   Bot\NetSync\commands\moderation\ban.js:15
>       let { user } = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
>             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'user' of
>   '(message.mentions.members.first(...) ||
>   message.guild.members.get(...))' as it is undefined.
>       at Object.run (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\NetSync\commands\moderation\ban.js:15:11)
>       at Client. (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\NetSync\index.js:36:34)
>       at Client.emit (events.js:323:22)
>       at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord
>   Bot\NetSync\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
>       at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord
>   Bot\NetSync\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord
>   Bot\NetSync\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord
>   Bot\NetSync\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
>       at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\NetSync\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
>       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
>       at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord
>   Bot\NetSync\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)

It was working perfectly fine before, not sure what went wrong. Here's my module exports.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    category: "moderation",
    description: "Bans the mentioned user.",
    usage: "<imputs>",
    run: (client, message, args) => {
    let { user } = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

    if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")){
        message.channel.send(permission);
    } else {
        if(!user)
            return message.channel.send(novalidmember);
        if(!user.bannable) 
            return message.channel.send("I cannot ban this user! Do they have a higher role? Do I have ban permissions?");

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
        if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

        user.ban({
            reason: `${reason}`
        })

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
         The embed is hidden.

        let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === `logs`);


        if (!logchannel){
            Sends a message to the channel.
            Logs the ban in a file.
        } else {
            Sends a message to the channel.
            Logs ban in the log channel.
          }


    }
}
}
```

Some of the code I've hidden as it isn't important. But I am still not sure what is wrong with the whole command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is mentioning that on the line below you can not ["destructure"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the result of `message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])`, because the result is `undefined`.

```js
let { user } = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
```

Is it possible that the result of `message.mentions.members.first()` and `message.guild.members.get(args[0])` is `undefined`? I do not see you checking for `undefined` before trying to get the user key from the object they return.

Here is what I would do instead of checking for a falsy value from `user` after assigning it: replace

```js
if (!user)
    return message.channel.send(novalidmember);
```

with something further up in the file (before you assign `user`) along the lines of below:

```
if (message.mentions.members.first() == undefined || message.guild.members.get(args[0]) == undefined)
{
    return message.channel.send(novalidmember);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you're saying? Would checking if it's undefined mean something like this: `if(!user) return message.channel.send(novalidmember);`?

Comment: Apologies if my answer was not clearer - you should be checking if `message.mentions.members.first()` or `message.guild.members.get(args[0])` is null before trying to assign them to `user`. The issue is arising because javascript has no idea what to make `user` out of, because those two statements are returning `undefined`.

Comment: For some reason changing `let { user } ...` to `let user ...` worked. Not sure why?

Comment: Point of clarity ``undefined !== null``.  In JavaScript they are two different concepts.  They are both "falsy" values, but not equals.

Comment: @PrinceBunBun981 When you do ``let { user } = ... `` you are telling it you want to pull out the user element of the object so ``let { user } = message.mentions.members.first()`` is functionally the same as saying ``let user = message.mentions.members.first().user``.  The problem is, memeber.user is a real thing in Discord.js but it becomes disassociated with the guild so all guild functions (such as bannable) don't exist at that level, and are therefore undefined.

Comment: @PrinceBunBun981 I have updated my answer with an explanation that (hopefully) makes more sense - I would recommend you read up what "destructuring" is, and why JS is not happy with the instructions you're giving it...

Comment: What Tarazed said helped explain it a lot. I understand what it means, and same with megubyte, I will look more into what that all means. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: @PrinceBunBun981 The reason that syntax exists is because you can pull out multiple properties at once by the way.  ``let {id, name, displayname} = message.mentions.members.first();``  will give you 3 variables including id, name and display name.

Comment: @Tarazed thanks for clearing that up, that explains a bunch to me about it.